# Website seems idle before loading content

Tags: wordpress, performance

When we navigate to our Wordpress website, it can sometimes remain idle for 3 to 10 seconds before appearing to load content. This can happen at random times. We have observed it happening on multiple internet networks and multiple devices, with no clear steps that can reproduce the behavior on our end. In other words, sometimes our site loads at a normal pace, but often we experience this:

[image: Firefox Performance recording of hanging website]

The above image is a Firefox "Performance" recording, but it does not actually reveal what causes the idle period. Is the server busy making database queries for our content that we need to optimize? Is the server putting our request on hold during times of high traffic for other sites? I can only speculate but would like to know how to better diagnose the problem.

Our host has suggested to update plugins, remove unused plugins and themes, and use a CDN. We tried this (except for the CDN) but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your hosting company is partly correct.  It's important to understand that all text in WordPress is stored in a database.  When you make a request, WP loads each active plugin and queries the database for both your content, and plugin properties/values.  This requires multiple queries of your database, before WordPress then processes and assembles your webpage for delivery to the client.  Each plugin has it's own database queries, so unloading unnecessary plugins can significantly help.

Each plugin adds to the delay.  A CDN helps alleviate this delay, by off loading image and static files to multiple servers, optimized and distributed for faster loading.  A caching server, will take the requests after they are assembled from the database and store the "final" assembled content in memory so that the next time the page is called, it's pulled directly from memory, rather than making a database query.

Now, what tools can you use to help?

I would highly suggest you look at the WP plugin Asset Cleanup and their tutorial.  You can use the free version and probably speed your site up substantially.

They have several videos of how to optimize your site using their plugin and other free tools that will help you optimize your site, and find javascript and CSS that is being downloaded, but not actually used.

They also have several excellent video tutorials, you can see an example here: https://youtu.be/ATXACFtcyKs and https://youtu.be/B8_QLVAgQiU.

Comment: Thanks for these tips and for teaching me a lot of things I didn't know! I will try out the WP plugin you suggest and report back later today or tomorrow.